# Use hook_hook_info() to implement hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()s in a separate file

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a lot of mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter()s in my module and I want to move them to a separate file (mymodule.form.inc), I found hook_hook_info() but I couldn't figure out how to use it for that specific case.

I tried adding:

```
$hooks['form_alter'] = array(
  'group' => 'form'
);
```

to mymodule_hook_info() but it didn't run the form alterers that I moved to the separate file. Any ideas how to get it to work?

Comment: How about including the this file in mymodule.module?

Comment: With `hook_hook_info()` there is not need to manually include the file.

Comment: If you only want to move implementations of one specific module, then hook_module_implements_alter() would do the trick. But be careful, there are people who would say this is a bad practice. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108884/hook-module-implements-alter-to-put-hook-implementations-into-separate-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works pretty well, the only thing is that if you want to implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, you need to add:

```
  $hooks['form_FORM_ID_alter'] = array(
    'group' => 'form'
  );
  return $hooks;
```

Comment: yep, it works that way. Too bad there's no generic way and we have to manually type each form alterer there.

Comment: There is a general way - you can use hook_form_alter() instead of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() in both places - in hook_hook_info() as well as in your hook name.

Answer (score 3):

Don't. This is not supported by Drupal core. In fact, hook_hook_info is intended for modules declaring hooks, not modules implementing them.

In addition, if two modules on a site declare a group for the same hook, all uses of the hook in $module.$group.inc files will break.

Instead, create stubs that do a module_load_include, and then a function call.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the solution found [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7#comment-8714).

Here's an easy way to get ALL hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() implementations loaded from a .inc file, WITHOUT declaring them each separately in `hook_hook_info()`.

In MY_MODULE.module add the following code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_hook_info_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_hook_info_alter(&$hooks) {
  $hooks['form_alter']['group'] = 'form'; 
}
```

Then in MY_MODULE.form.inc make sure to add the following code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
}

// Add all MY_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter() functions below here.
```

With the above `MY_MODULE_form_alter()` declared in this .inc file (even if it's empty), all `MY_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter()` implementations declared in the same file will get loaded properly. Without this function the file will not be loaded at all.

This works because `drupal_prepare_form()` calls `hook_form_alter()` (and loads this .inc file) before calling `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` for each form build.

Comment: It is almost all correct, except that the hook to implement is `hook_hook_info()`, not `hook_hook_info_alter()`. There is not need to define `hook_form_alter()` in the included file, as the include file is first loaded, and then Drupal checks the function implementing the hook exists. In  the case it doesn't exists, the file is already included, and Drupal would find the implementations of `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

Comment: The code I copied over is a solution that lets you avoid declaring each FORM_ID_alter() in hook_hook_info(), in case you find that convenient.