# hook_module_implements_alter() to put hook implementations into separate files - bad practice?

Tags: 7, hooks

In a number of modules I wrote, I use hook_module_implements_alter() to split up the *.module file, and to move hook implementations into separate files.

The main reason is that I passionately hate long files. (and yes, this does make me unhappy about a lot of the files in Drupal 7 and contrib)

Examples:

- [nestedbox_core_module_implements_alter()](https://github.com/donquixote/drupal-nestedbox/blob/d234047c24b45ca64907c45dd1ecc327afbe3c28/nestedbox_core.module#L7)
- [xautoload_module_implements_alter()](https://github.com/donquixote/drupal-xautoload/blob/6edc54cf3786f85c1ca9d1a0f239350d98fb0aa2/xautoload.module#L66)

I know there are a few things to consider:

1. It might not work for all hooks. E.g. boot or install, or hooks that are not called via module_implements().
2. It is important to include the respective file from within the hook_module_implements_alter() implementation, due to the way that module_implements() works.

Now I heard from a long-time and well-known Drupal developer that this practice is problematic. https://drupal.org/node/2230319 (topic starter, and comments #5 and #11).

Before I start moving functions around, I would like to hear from others whether and why this is bad, both technically and aesthetically.

EDIT:
I guess this could be split in two questions:

1. Is it good or bad to split up your *.module file, so that hook implementations live elsewhere?
2. Is hook_module_implements_alter() reliable enough, or should I rather use `include_once __DIR__ . '/MYMODULE.filename.inc'` directly in the *.module file? What could possibly go wrong by using hook_module_implements_alter() for this?

Comment: I want others to weigh in on the split, but I think it may be good.  I am really in the why of #2.

Comment: (btw, some of what is in the answer is stuff i already know, but that is nevertheless relevant and essential to make this useful for other people. And they confirm that splitting up is a common practice. So both get +1 from me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the piece of information that was missing.
EDIT: And another one.

## Problem with module_invoke()

`module_invoke_all()` always calls `module_implements()`, which checks the module include file by checking both `hook_hook_info()` and `hook_module_implements_alter()`.

However, `module_invoke()` only checks `hook_hook_info()` and *not* `hook_module_implements_alter()`.

`module_invoke()` is called e.g. in `_block_render_blocks()` for `hook_block_view()`.
This means that `hook_module_implements_alter()` is not a good solution to split a `hook_block_view()` implementation into a separate file.

This has been a problem in Crumbs, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2328535.

For other hooks it generally works ok, but you never know if a specific module wants to use `module_invoke()` instead of `module_invoke_all()`.

## module_implements() cache polluted in bootstrap.

Another problem is caused by a core issue reported here:
[module_implements_cache() can be polluted by hook_boot() implementations calling module_invoke_all() directly or indirectly](https://www.drupal.org/node/496170)

This applies only to *non-boot modules*, where it can happen that the implementation of `hook_module_implements_alter()` is never discovered.

1. An unexpected chain of events causes `module_implements($hook)` being called from `hook_boot()`.
   The `$hook` can be any random hook, it does not need to be related to the module we are working on.
2. This causes `module_implements('module_implements_alter')` to be called.
3. Drupal looks for all implementations of `hook_module_implements_alter()`.
   At this time, `MODULENAME.module` is not included yet.
   Therefore, for the rest of the request, Drupal assumes that the implementation `MODULENAME_module_implements_alter()` does not exist.
4. Later in the request, implementations of other hooks are being discovered, but the implementations by MODULENAME are not being found, because `MODULENAME_module_implements_alter()` is not being executed.

## Alternatives

### require_once

Alternatives have already been mentioned. Instead of these tricks, one can include the file directly. There may be a tiny performance impact but this is probably overshadowed by a lot of other things in Drupal.

But, instead of using `module_load_include()`, I would suggest a more direct solution:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/crumbs.block.inc';
```

Or to be PHP 5.2 compatible:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/crumbs.block.inc';
```

### Why not module_load_include()?

There is generally no need to call `module_load_include()`, it could even be detrimental, if the *.module file is included from you-dont-know-where (e.g. from `settings.php`), and you don't know if `module_load_include()` is available.

This function is mostly there to help you determine the location of *other* modules. But if you are including *within the same module*, it is generally safer and easier and faster to work with relative file paths and explicit `require_once`.

### Call to helper function

As mentioned by Jimajamma, you can also implement the hook in the main `*.module` file, and then include another file and call a helper function from there. This is done e.g. in Display suite.

This solution is ok, although I think it still clutters the main file, and gives you even more places to look.

And here likewise you can use require_once instead of `module_load_include()`, if it is within the same module.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful breakdown. I needed a helpful shove to get me to consolidate a half dozen related but separate custom modules for a client into one. I think I'll stop trying to over think it, and simply `require` the extra files. A good naming convention for these files will help, too, and then the whole thing becomes much more parsible.

Comment: Why would you combine different modules into one? Separation is good! (depends, of course)

Comment: Oh separation of concerns is a must! And modules that can remain abstract (I.e be modules), should. On this particular project, I seem to have at one point thought that the same paradigm applied to the business logic that was unfolding and evolving within the app. It's not really the same case, and several of the modules aren't *really* modules but collections of PAC logic that make no sense without each other.

Comment: Why don't you use [`hook_hook_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info_alter/7) instead? Do the same considerations/problems apply if I use `hook_hook_info_alter()` to split the hook implementations in a separate file?

Comment: hook_hook_info_alter() applies to all implementations of this hook. Thus, it will have unintended side effects on other modules.

Answer (score 2):

Any major project I have worked on has broken things up into manageable and easily assignable pieces; basically ending up like @tenken mentioned here, or to the point where `foo.module` ends up being only includes:

```
<?php

module_load_include('inc', 'foo', 'foo.defines');         // bring in our define()s
module_load_include('inc', 'foo', 'foo.HOOK1');           // bring in our HOOK1 functions
module_load_include('inc', 'foo', 'foo.HOOK2');           // bring in our HOOK2 functions

// ...etc
```

Of course, I have also seen, and used, situations where admin only or otherwise rarely used hooks are included like:

```
function foo_HOOK(/* $args */) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'foo', 'foo.HOOK');
  return _foo_HOOK(/* $args */);  // _foo_hook() is defined in foo.HOOK.inc
}
```

Comment: yes, seen that and done it myself. both of it. although I recently prefer just include_once \_\_DIR__ . '/filename.inc'. So.. i guess we are clear then about question 1, it is far from unorthodox to split stuff up. Remains question two, whether anything bad could happen if you use hook_module_implements_alter() for that. Or how big the performance benefit could be for not including the file on an average request, where e.g. hook_menu() is not called.

Comment: Btw I don't personally like the _foo_HOOK() trick all too much, it makes me look in two places instead of one..

Comment: Btw, you can simplify to module_load_include('defines.inc', 'foo'). But what's lrfm?

Comment: lol, lrfm was the module I cut and pasted that out of and forgot to change to foo :)

Comment: as for your simplification, yes, that would certainly work, but the first argument is supposed to be the type of file, and per the examples in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7, I imho doubt what the "drupal powers at be" intended, but certainly less typing.

Comment: I think the person who originally designed this function meant it to be used exactly like I suggest. But this is so weird and ass backwards that noone else actually picks up on that, including those writing the doc page.

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/697946

Comment: well, to each his own, the end result is that this is just a fancy wrapper for figuring out how to define `$file` in an eventual `require_once $file;` :)

Answer (score 1):

If I try to breakup my .module file across multiple files I tend to do what Features for D7 does for its "included" files which it uses include_once() for:

```
include_once('MYMODULE.features.inc');
```

For D7 I still use my module's name "function namespacing" for these included files, and private module functions typically are prefixed as "_MYMODULE_foo()".

This answer kinda ignores your desired use of Autoloading classes and any OO related patterns you're trying to use within your code (code dependencies, etc).

In your linked issue it sounds like you want to use hook_module_implements_alter() to be a readable index of what files have what functions in your .module file. I think sane 'MYMODULE.PURPOSE.inc' filenaming is enough to clue a developer of the use of that include file within your module.

Comment: The idea is to include the respective file only when it is needed. I am thinking about performance there, but I don't know the actual performance impact. I guess with APC or similar it does not make a big difference, but I never measured it.

Comment: @donquixote if you are thinking about performance, then install APC or other opcode cache and don't bother with splitting so much.